# Errors with a Template in C++ regarding operators

Tags: c++

In my project, I am using a header file for an arrayList. During the main method, I initialize an object of type arrayList where FriendToken is another class defined in my project. However, this gives me quite a few errors while compiling arrayList.h. Apparently, I cannot use the built-in copy method and the operator == is unrecognized for an object of type FriendToken. Should I overload the == operator for FriendToken and if so, how should I do that?

Both errors are marked in the body ArrayList.h.

ArrayList.h:

```
#ifndef arrayList_h
#define arrayList_h

#include "linearList.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;
template<class T>
class arrayList : public linearList<T> 
{
public:
    // constructor, copy constructor and destructor
    arrayList(int initialCapacity = 10);
    arrayList(const arrayList<T>&);
    ~arrayList() {delete [] element;}
    // ADT methods
    bool empty() const {return listSize == 0;}
    int size() const {return listSize;}
    T& get(int theIndex) const;
    int indexOf(const T& theElement) const;
    void erase(int theIndex);
    void insert(int theIndex, const T& theElement);
    void output(ostream& out) const;
    void changeLength1D(T*& a, int oldLength, int newLength);
    // additional method
    int capacity() const {return arrayLength;}
protected:
    void checkIndex(int theIndex) const;
    // throw illegalIndex if theIndex invalid
    T* element;      // 1D array to hold list elements
    int arrayLength;       // capacity of the 1D array
    int listSize;          // number of elements in list
};
template<class T> 
arrayList<T>::arrayList(int initialCapacity)
{
    // Constructor.
    arrayLength = initialCapacity;
    element = new T[arrayLength];
    listSize = 0;
}
template<class T>
arrayList<T>::arrayList(const arrayList<T>& theList)
{
    // Copy constructor.
    arrayLength = theList.arrayLength;
    listSize = theList.listSize;
    element = new T[arrayLength];
    copy(theList.element, theList.element + listSize, element); 
}
template<class T>
void arrayList<T>::checkIndex(int theIndex) const
{
    // Verify that theIndex is between 0 and 
    // listSize - 1.
    if (theIndex < 0 || theIndex >= listSize)
    {
        cout << "index = " << theIndex << " size = " 
            << listSize;
    } 
}
template<class T>
T& arrayList<T>::get(int theIndex) const
{
    // Return element whose index is theIndex.
    // Throw illegalIndex exception if no such
    // element.
    checkIndex(theIndex);
    return element[theIndex];
}
template<class T>
int arrayList<T>::indexOf(const T& theElement)const
{
    // Return index of first occurrence of theElement.
        // search for theElement
        int theIndex = (int) (find(element, element
        + listSize, theElement) - element);
    // check if theElement was found
    if (theIndex == listSize)
        return -1; // not found
    else return theIndex; 
}
template<class T>
void arrayList<T>::erase(int theIndex)
    {// Delete the element whose index is theIndex.
    checkIndex(theIndex);
    // valid index, shift elements with higher index
//PROBLEM********************************************
    copy(element + theIndex + 1, element + listSize,element + theIndex);
    element[--listSize].~T(); // invoke destructor
}
template<class T>
void arrayList<T>::insert(int theIndex, const T& theElement)
{
    // Insert theElement.
    if (theIndex < 0 || theIndex > listSize)

    {// invalid index
        // code to throw an exception comes here
    }
    // valid index, make sure we have space
    if (listSize == arrayLength)
    {
        // no space, double capacity
        changeLength1D(element, arrayLength, 
        2 * arrayLength);
        arrayLength *= 2;
    }
    // shift elements right one position
//PROBLEM***************************************
    copy_backward(element + theIndex, element + listSize, element + listSize + 1);
    element[theIndex] = theElement;
    listSize++;
}
template<class T>
void arrayList<T>::output(ostream& out) const
{
    // Put the list into the stream out.
    copy(element, element + listSize, ostream_iterator<T>(out, "  ")); 
}
template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const arrayList<T>& x)
{x.output(out); return out;}

template<class T>
void changeLength1D(T*& a, int oldLength, int newLength)
{
    if (newLength < 0)
        throw illegalParameterValue();
    T* temp = new T[newLength];     
    // new array
    int number = min(oldLength, newLength); 
    // number to copy
    copy(a, a + number, temp);
    delete [] a;                    
    // deallocate old memory
    a = temp;
}


#endif
```

FriendToken.h

```
#ifndef FriendToken_h
#define FriendToken_h

#include <string>

using namespace std; 

class FriendToken
{
private:
    string birthDate, name, homeTown;
public:
    FriendToken(string birthDate = "01/01", string name = "John, Smith", string homeTown = "New York");
    string getBirthDate();
    string getName();
    string getHomeTown();
    bool equals(FriendToken a);
};

#endif
```

FriendToken.cpp

```
#include "FriendToken.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

FriendToken::FriendToken(string birthDate, string name, string homeTown)
{
    this->birthDate = birthDate;
    this->name = name;
    this->homeTown = homeTown;
}
string FriendToken::getBirthDate()
{
    return birthDate;
}
string FriendToken:: getName()
{
    return name;
}
string FriendToken::getHomeTown()
{
    return homeTown;
}
bool FriendToken::equals(FriendToken a)
{
    return (name == a.getName()) && (homeTown == a.getHomeTown()) && (birthDate == a.getBirthDate());
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to read. Maybe you could narrow it down more.

Comment: Have you tried adding an `operator==` function to your class? Did it help?

Comment: That helps somewhat. Operator errors no longer occur but the methods copy and copy_backward still say they don't work with FriendToken.

Comment: You should never be afraid of experimenting and trying things out. If it doesn't work then you learned something and that makes you a better programmer as well.

Comment: After overloading the operator, I disabled the warnings on copy and copy_backward, which seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: You shouldn't just arbitrarily disable warnings you don't understand, you should learn what they mean and then fix them.  Remember, a warning is just an error that doesn't prevent the compiler from finishing its job.  I've seen compiler warnings in the past that turned out to be real bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without the compiler errors.

Either way, this is how you overload the operator.

```
template<typename T>
bool arrayList::operator== (const arrayList<T>& theList) 
{
    // Compare the values, and return a bool result.
}
```